# MPI All_reduce issue with a specific computer

Tags: mpi

I am trying to put in place a little MPI cluster. I have 3 computers and followed those instructions (in french sorry): https://www.supinfo.com/articles/single/922-parallelisation-linux-mettre-place-cluster-mpi

I have reproduced the issue with this piece of code:

```
#include <mpi.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    MPI_Init(&argc,&argv);

    int world_size;
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &world_size);

    int world_rank;
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &world_rank);

    char pro_name[MPI_MAX_PROCESSOR_NAME];
    int name_len;
    MPI_Get_processor_name(pro_name, &name_len);

    printf("HW! I'm pro %s, rank %d, out of %d processors.\n", pro_name, world_rank, world_size);


    int sum;
    MPI_Allreduce(&world_size, &sum, 1, MPI_INT, MPI_SUM, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    printf("sum = %d\n", sum);

    MPI_Finalize();
}
```

I run it like that:

```
mpicc -o test_mpi test_mpi.c
mpirun --hostfile build_mpi/mpi_hostfile test_mpi
```

It prints correctly this:

```
HW! I'm pro master, rank 0, out of 2 processors.
HW! I'm pro slave1, rank 1, out of 2 processors.
sum = 4
sum = 4
```

But when I add a third computer in the cluster, I get only this:

```
HW! I'm pro master, rank 0, out of 3 processors.
HW! I'm pro slave1, rank 1, out of 3 processors.
HW! I'm pro slave2, rank 2, out of 3 processors.
```

It does not want to do the All_reduce instruction, it is blocked there, no error message! I have to sigkill it. With the master and the slave2 it does not work neither.

I am not sure about a communication issue. All computers do know each other thanks to a ssh-copy-id, and everyone can ping the others. The shared folder is done with a sshfs.

Is it the firewall ? Does MPI use a different port to communicate the standard output (ssh 22 port) and the internal communications (MPI_Allreduce) ?
Any other idea ?

Each machine has ubuntu 16.04 and MPI 1.10.2 .
Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: Open MPI needs more than `SSH` to work correctly. First, you should disable the firewall on your three machines.

Comment: Thank you Gilles. But what does it need in more ?

Comment: it requires TCP connection for `oob/tcp` (out of band management over TCP) and `btl/tcp` (MPI communications over TCP).

Comment: Thank you for those information, I'll check that but it's certainly this kind of issue